# Php safemysql class получить insert id

Tags: php, mysqli

Как с помощью [этого](https://habrahabr.ru/post/165069/) класса получить insert id запроса?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO domains SET name = ?s, license = ?s, enddate = ?s, session = ?s";
$db->query($sql,$name,$code,$ends,"begin");
die($db->insert_id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод называется `insertId()`

```
die($db->insertId());
```